# Не пингуется камера HIKVISION

Tags: linux, ip, камера

Подключил через коммутатор IP камеру HIKVISION, если просканировать сеть при помощи `arp-scan`, то камера видна

> 192.168.1.64  84:9a:40:f6:d6:b1   Hangzhou Hikvision Digital Technology Co.,Ltd.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но камера не пингуется и не могу зайти на web морду

IP моей машины: `192.168.0.42/23`

Comment: *камера не пингуется* А подробнее? Timeout? Destination unreacheable? No route to host? что-то ещё? *IP моей машины: 192.168.0.42/23* А настройки камеры? особенно маска сети...

Comment: да у меня была не верная маска сети, сейчас поменял на 192.168.0.42/24 и добавил 192.168.1.42/24, камера пингуется, верно ли я сделал, то что добавил еще один ip к своему сетевому интерфейсу или нужно было роутинг настраивать?

Comment: А на зачем вообще камеру в отдельную подсеть выносить?

Comment: Она по умолчанию в отдельной подсети была

Comment: Просто "так сложилось"? Бессмысленно. Соберите всё в одну подсеть.

Comment: Да положил в одну подсеть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть на вашей машине маска /23, но на камере она /24 скорее всего. Ответ камера отправляет на шлюз, которого в сети нет. Добавьте на интерфейс адрес 192.168.1.x/24 и можно попробовать подключиться.

```
ip a a 192.168.1.12/24 dev enp2s0
```